# Coordinate or cumulative adjectives? Beautiful mysterious dreamy feelings

Tags: adjectives

I want to express that something brings me some feelings, then I wrote the following sentences.

> 1. It brings me beautiful mysterious dreamy feelings.
> 2. It brings me beautiful and mysterious dreamy feelings.
> 3. It brings me beautiful, mysterious and dreamy feelings.
> 4. It brings me beautiful mysterious and dreamy feelings.

But after I read [this](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-adjectives), I think that mysterious and dreamy pair with the feelings as a unit, and then beautiful modify the unit. So I think the first and the last sentence are more correct.

For the second sentence, it seems that beautiful and mysterious are coordinate adjectives and to modify dreamy feelings. Is that right?

Comment: @MickSharpe - Wait, what do you think is the problem with #1?  There's nothing wrong with chaining adjectives like that (cf, *one-eyed one-horned flying purple people eater*).

Answer (score 0):

> **Coordinate adjectives** modify nouns in an equal way. They describe the same feature. They are often called "equal adjectives." Most coordinate adjectives are adjectives of opinion or evaluation. We don't generally use more than one adjective from any of the other categories together because they sound redundant.
>
> **Cumulative adjectives** build upon each other and must be in a certain order. They are equally important and give different types >of information

[Source #1](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-adjectives-placement.php) [Source #2](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-5/modifiers-adjectives-and-adverbs/lesson-4/order-of-adjectives)

I've analyzed the web and have to say that *"beautiful"* and *"mysterious"* together are **"Coordinate adjectives"**. And it looks like *"dreamy"* tends to add similar characteristics to the object! So basically it is also a **"Coordinate adjective"**.

We should also clarify that *"beautiful"* and *"mysterious"* are equally modifying the "dreamy feelings".

So based on this explanation **(Sometimes a comma is inserted to clarify that two adjectives modify an adjective-noun combination instead of all the adjectives modifying the single noun.)** we need to separate the two with a comma.

In result we get that #3 *"It brings me beautiful, mysterious and dreamy feelings."* is the correct sentence which means that *"It brings you mysterious and dreamy feelings which are beautiful!"*

Comment: I can't cleary define whether your comment is indulging or not. What do you mean by "in the same way"?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean, and punctuation is important. For example, if you mean that it brings you beautiful feelings, mysterious feelings and dreamy feelings, then:

> It brings me beautiful, mysterious, and dreamy feelings.

The commas typically indicate that you can change the order of the adjectives without affecting the meaning. (However, the second comma is optional in American English depending on the style that you adhere to.)

The other option is to create a compound adjective by combining two of the words together with a hyphen. In your example, however, that wouldn't really make sense to me because the words are so different. Nevertheless:

> It brings me beautiful-mysterious and dreamy feelings.

Here *beautiful* describes *mysterious* and the combination describes feelings.

> It brings me beautiful, mysterious-dreamy feelings.

> It brings me beautiful mysterious-dreamy feelings.

Here *mysterious* describes *dreamy* and the combination describes feelings. With the comma, *beautiful* describes *feelings*. Without the comma, *beautiful* describes *mysterious-dreamy*.

Words that belong together a little better might make more sense. Consider *long*, *curly*, *dark*, *blond*:

> She had long, dark, curly, blond hair.

They each describe *hair* and you can change the order.

You can also create compound adjectives depending on what you mean. For example:

> She had long, dark, curly-blond hair.

> She had long, curly, dark-blond hair.